# Comparing two date and check if given date is in past or same or future

Tags: momentjs

I am using moment.js to compare two dates.

```
const somedayMom = moment(new Date(event.target.value)); // '2021-12-31'
const todayMom = moment();
if (moment(somedayMom).isSameOrAfter(todayMom)) {
            
} else {
            
 }
```

Now from input I am getting `'2021-12-31'` and today is 31st December, so it should fall in if() block, but it falls into else part. What I am doing wrong here. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .format to include only year, month and day.

```
if (moment(somedayMom.format('YYYY-MM-DD')).isSameOrAfter(todayMom.format('YYYY-MM-DD'))) {
} 
else {
 }
```

PS. Formatting the first moment would be unneccessary in your scenaro if event.target.value returns a right string.